# How to set HTML text input to always have 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, html

I have a normal HTML **text** input that will contain currency values calculated from other values and rounded to `2 decimal places`

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="prevloans" name="prevloans" readonly='readonly'>
```

The issue is that if the value is something like 23.30, it will only show it as 23.3. How do I make sure two digits are always shown without using input type="number"?

Comment: How are you setting the value? Most likely you are setting it as a number, which gets auto-cast to a string - you want to manually cast to string with a trailing 0.

Comment: @LukeStorry like this : $('#' + pid + '8').text((sum.toFixed(2)));

Comment: var number = 12132.2343243
var rounded = Math.round(number * 10) / 10  , it will return `12132.2`

Answer (score 0):

I can see that the field is a "readonly" type. Which means that you can't use `input` event listener for that. However, what you can do it call a function wherever you place the value inside the field. It is pure javascript, independent of jQuery.

```js
function setValue(val){
  let field = document.querySelector("#prevloans");
  field.value = Number(val).toFixed(2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `HTML` and a little bit of `Javascript`.

Since you don't want to use `number` type on input, then use a pattern to match the format that you want, in this case `x.xx`. So a pattern like this one `[\d]+([\.][\d]{2})` would apply.

```js
var inpObj = document.getElementById("myinp");
inpObj.addEventListener('input', () => {
  if (!inpObj.checkValidity()) {
    console.log(inpObj.validationMessage);
  } else {
    console.log('you typed: ' + inpObj.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinp" name="myinp" pattern="[\d]+([\.][\d]{2})">
```

Since this is a `readonly` input, `pattern` will not help, then 2-3  simple lines of `JS` can help.

```js
function myFunction() {
let inp = document.querySelector('#myinp')
inp.value = parseFloat(inp.value).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
<input type="text" id="myinp" name="myinp" value="23.3" readonly="readonly">
</body>
```

Comment: *"calculated from other values"* ....  *" without using input type=number"*. The input is readonly

Comment: @charlietfl i did not saw that :D...., you are correct, i changed my answer.

Comment: @PeterDarmis I guess you didn't see but I have posted the similar solution for that

Comment: @PranavRustagi most probably, so i will up-vote it! :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Casts it to a float and then a string. It should apply changes in real time as the user types.

```
$('#prevloans').on('input', function(){
    $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: *"in real time as the user types"* ... not using change event it won't. Try it yourself

Comment: Ahh yes need to use the `input` event. Always mess that up. Will edit my answer. Cheers

Answer (score -2):

**Note:** You need to use `up` and `down` arrows (after inserting numbers):

Try this:

```html
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="prevloans" name="prevloans" step="0.01" >
```

Also, checkout: [https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50892510.html#:~:text=Allow%202%20decimal%20places%20in,form%20is%20submit%2C%20not%20onblur](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50892510.html#:%7E:text=Allow%202%20decimal%20places%20in,form%20is%20submit%2C%20not%20onblur).